# jQuery: check checkboxes for columns with the same names that are visible?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to use the classnames of table cells to check checkboxes of the corresponding value, using jQuery. I don't know if I need to use `eval` or something similar.

Code:

```
<p style="float:right;">
These columns are visible: 
<br/><input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="col1" /> Col1
<br/><input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="col2" /> Col2
<br/><input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="col3" /> Col3
</p>
<table id="comptable">
<tr> 
<td class="col1">Col1</td>
<td class="col2" style="display:none;">Col2</td>
<td class="col3">Col3</td>
</tr>
</table>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var visible_tds = $('comptable td:visible');
    // Check the checkboxes that correspond to the visible table cells.
    $.each(visible_tds, function() { 
       // use ($(this).attr('class'))
       // to check the checkbox?
    });
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TJ3zN/5/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Check the checkboxes that correspond to the visible ones
    $('#comptable td:visible').each(function() { 
        $("input[value='" + $(this).attr('class') + "']").attr('checked', true);
    });
});
```

The `input[value='']` selector will return any inputs with the attribute `value` that matches whatever you specify inbetween the  `''` marks.

You were also missing a # from the beginning of your the `compatable` selector. The table has the *ID* of compatable so to select an ID you have to put a # before it.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#comptable td:visible').each(function() {
       $("input[type=checkbox][value='" + $(this).attr("class") + "']").prop("checked", true);
    });
});
```

That should do the trick. It finds the checkbox with `value` equal to the value of the `class` attribute of each visible `td`, and set the `checked` property to true (note that you will have to be using jQuery 1.6 at least to use the `prop` function, otherwise, you'll have to use `attr`).

You can see it running [here](http://jsfiddle.net/interdream/TJ3zN/8/).